# React Native: How do I apply a custom function to an array of objects and return the modified array in Javascript with an additional field?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I am working on measuring distance between two points using the `geolib` library in react native. I am trying to figure out how best to map an existing array of places each in a object and add a field that shows the distance between that place and a static location. I feel like I am close but unsure as at the moment I am receiving a promise I am unsure how to resolve. Below is my code, appreciate the help:

```
  import { getDistance } from "geolib";
    
const state ={
      places:[
        {
          site_id:'1',
          latitude: 40.763470,
          longitude: -73.929032
        },
        {
          site_id:'2',
          latitude: 40.6010,
          longitude: -73.9643
        },
        
      ],
    location: {
    latitude: 40.8019,
    longitude: -73.9786
    } 
    }
    
    const  calculateDistance = async (start_x,start_y, end_x,end_y) => {
      try {
        let distance = await getDistance(
          {
            latitude: start_x,
            longitude: start_y,
          },
          {
            latitude: end_x,
            longitude: end_y,
          },
          //(accuracy = 100)
        );
          return(distance);  
        } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
    
    const map1 = state.places.map(court=> ({ ...place, distance: calculateDistance(
            place.latitude,
            place.longitude,
            location.latitude,
            location.longitude
          ) }))

console.log(map1)
```

I currently get a promise.

**Desired Output**

```
places:[
        {
          site_id:'1',
          latitude: 40.763470,
          longitude: -73.929032,
distance: //whatever the distance is
        },
        {
          site_id:'2',
          latitude: 40.6010,
          longitude: -73.9643,
distance: //whatever the distance is
        },
        
      ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't appear as though [getDistance](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geolib#getdistancestart-end-accuracy--1) is actually an async function. You can simply consume its return value.

```
const state = {
  places: [
    {
      site_id: "1",
      latitude: 40.76347,
      longitude: -73.929032
    },
    {
      site_id: "2",
      latitude: 40.601,
      longitude: -73.9643
    }
  ],
  location: {
    latitude: 40.8019,
    longitude: -73.9786
  }
};

const calculateDistance = (start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y) => {
  try {
    let distance = getDistance( // <-- not async function, no need to await
      {
        latitude: start_x,
        longitude: start_y
      },
      {
        latitude: end_x,
        longitude: end_y
      }
      //(accuracy = 100)
    );
    return distance;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

const map1 = state.places.map((place) => ({
  ...place,
  distance: calculateDistance(
    place.latitude,
    place.longitude,
    state.location.latitude,
    state.location.longitude
  )
}));

console.log(JSON.stringify(map1));
```

[image: Edit react-native-how-do-i-apply-a-custom-function-to-an-array-of-objects-and-return]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that happens because `getDistance` function is async as you noticed since you are using `await`. So when you are mapping every value of that array using the `getDistance` function, all the mapped values are `Promises` (and most likely unresolved) so it just returns that synchronously.

Now what you probably want to do is:

1. Create an async function to map all the values

   const getDistances = async array => Promise.all(array.map(async location => {
   const distance = await.getDistance(location.latitude, location.longitude, state.latitude, state.longitude)
   return {...distance, location}
   }))
2. Use that new function to retrieve the values and console.log like this, using `.then()` or `async/await`:

   getDistances(state.places).then(console.log)

I think some of your variables had typos so my code have them too but I think you can get the point. What we are trying to do is to `resolve` the `getDistances` function once every location have gathered its location.